# What's $ab$ if we have: $\frac {5030}{5555}=\frac{a+b}{10}+\frac{b}{10^3}+\frac{a}{10^4}+\frac{a+b}{10^5}+\frac{b}{10^7}+...$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation-method

> What's $ab$ if we have: $\frac {5030}{5555}=\frac{a+b}{10}+\frac{b}{10^3}+\frac{a}{10^4}+\frac{a+b}{10^5}+\frac{b}{10^7}+\frac{a}{10^8}+\frac{a+b}{10^9}+...$

I have classified the terms of RHS and calculated for example: $$S_1=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10^5}+\frac{1}{10^9}+...=\frac{10^3}{10^4-1}$$ 
But suppose we have calculated all of such sums as $S_1,S_2,S_3$ to get:
$$(a+b)S_1+aS_2+bS_3=\frac {5030}{5555}$$
Here I stopped!!

Comment: Use long division to get the first 9 decimals for 5030/5555 .

Comment: That's reducible  to 1006/1111 but seems doesn't help much

Comment: $S_1=\frac {10^3}{10^4-1}$.

Comment: Yes your'e right,I had some mistake,but this doesn't affect the overall problem much!

Comment: Do $a$ and $b$ need to be integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide:
$$
\frac{5030}{5555} = 0.90549054905490549\dots
=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{5}{10^3}+\frac{4}{10^4}+\frac{9}{10^5}
+\frac{5}{10^7}+\frac{4}{10^8}+\dots
$$
So with $9=a+b, b=5, a=4$, this matches the required form.

Comment: Nice solution (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$$S_1=\frac {10^3}{10^4-1}=\frac {1000}{9999}\\
S_2=\frac 1{1000}S_1; S_3=\frac 1{100}S_1\\
\Rightarrow \frac{1000}{9999}\left[(a+b)+\frac a{1000}+\frac b{100}\right]=\frac {5030}{5555}\\
1001a+1010b=9054
$$
If $a,b$ are positive integers, then from 
$$1000(a+b)\;+\;10b\;+\;a=9\;0\;5\;4$$
we can deduce by inspection that one of the solutions is 
$$a=4, b=5\\
ab=20\;\blacksquare$$

Comment: Now what  do you think about $ab$? Can we get it?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: Yes  they   are integers

Comment: Solved, if $a,b$ are integers.

Comment: Please explain why $a=4,b=5$?!

Comment: See new edit in solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found $a+b = 9 \cdot 503$, just substitute $b=9 \cdot 503 - a$ into the final equation and then you should be able to find the values of $b$ and $a$, as well as their product.

Comment: I think we have essentially just one equation and 2 variables!!